# Javacore | Blocked Thread | PhysicalConnection.isClosed | JDBC

Tags: oracle, jdbc, websphere, database-connection, blocked

Web app with Spring MVC and JDBC is deployed in websphere and almost daily I could see 2-4 javacore files generated.
Upon analyzing these files using IBM `jca.jar`, I found below issues which is actually causing thread to be BLOCKED

**State** - Blocked

**Monitor** - Waiting for Monitor Lock on oracle/jdbc/driver/T4CConnection@0x00000000C889BAE0

**Java Stack** - at oracle/jdbc/driver/PhysicalConnection.isClosed(PhysicalConnection.java:1481(Compiled Code))

**Trigger Action** - 1TISIGINFO     Dump Event "user" (00004000) received

Next error line denotes below function which calls `isClosed()` method.

In the code I could see below lines.

```
boolean validateConnection(Connection connection){
      if(connection != null && !connection.isClosed()){
             return true;
     }
  return false;
}
```

Above method is called for each HTTP Request made by user action, and session is bind to HTTP Session.

But when and how these javacore gets generated I am not getting idea.

I see next [link](https://bz.apache.org/netbeans/show_bug.cgi?id=221602), which looks related to this problem.

Oracle Dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
    <version>10.2.0.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Oracle Version - Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0

Websphere Version - 8.5.5.17

Comment: Is your question or concern about what is causing the javacores to be generated?
In that case, you can look at the 'signal' area to see how the javacore was triggered, and the 'current thread' section will be useful if the javacore was triggered by specific activity on a particular running thread.
This problem determination info may be useful.
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/problem-determination-javacore-files-websphere-application-server#3.1

Comment: @GaryDeVal 1TISIGINFO     Dump Event "user" (00004000) received, yes i need to understand what is actually causing these javacores to be generated, i understand that BLOCKED threads might be creating these, maybe calling isClosed() as mentioned in the link, but need to be sure and should i removes connection active check

Comment: "Dump Event "user" received"  means that someone triggered the javacore with an external signal,  for example 'kill -3 <pid>' on Linux. If the javacore were triggered by some internal function of WAS, you should see a message in the logs about it, and the 'current thread' callstack would also point to what code was triggering the javacore.

Comment: Have you tried using a newer version of the Oracle driver ojdbc14 (which means it is for Java 1.4), version 10.2.0.3.0 is pretty old, maybe you're encountering a problem that is fixed in a newer version of the driver.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel COuld be, tried upgrading version but seems this is more strict, so need to handle more scenarios. But yes upgrade might solve these issues.

Comment: @GaryDeVal Yes i checked the logs, but could not see any issues as such